# How to submit formtastic via ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic, remote-forms

So i have a form generated by formtastic and it's working :

```
<%semantic_form_for(Model.new,:url=>{:action=>"fooobar"}) do |f|%>
<%end%>
```

i was wondering if there's any way to submit this form via Ajax like

`remote_semantic_form_for`

or

`semantic_remote_form_for`

because I have full functionality but it'll be a lot better if i don't have to reload the page on every submit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got this working with `semantic_remote_form_for`

Comment: In Rails 3 you should go with :remote => true option.

Comment: Thanks, I'm now using Rails 2.3.10